# argparse in python3 - cannot add argument with - in name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my sample program:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   import os
   import string
   import argparse

   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="get all versions")
   parser.add_argument(test-version)
   version = parser.parse_args()

   print(version.test-version)
```

When I run the python script, it throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'test'
```

If I try the same example with argument "test" instead of "test-version" it works fine.

It is important for me to have the - in my argument name.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can have a `-` in your argument name, so the issue is something else.

Comment: I'm assuming you have quotes in  `parser.add_argument('test-version')` in your actual code? (This is why it's important to make sure the code you put up is actually generating the error you say it is)

Comment: There is no quotes and there is no reason for assumption. I gave the exact code . It is a very simple 4 line code . The only thing i had to add to make it "complete" as per your suggestion was to add the shebang and import lines.

Comment: No. That's not your full code. If it was, you would be getting `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`. Because you have not defined `test-version`, nor could you, because it's not a valid variable name.

Comment: I tried running your example and it outputs `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`, not `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'test'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(getattr(version, 'test-version'))
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you can't have a `-` in a variable name, because it's the subtraction operator. So, in your code, the interpreter is trying to do `version.test - version`, which doesn't work because `version` doesn't have a `.test` attribute and you can't subtract a namespace from something. If you want to use `-` in the argument, you need to set the `dest=` parameter in [`.add_argument()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method).

For example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="get all versions")
parser.add_argument('--test-version', dest='test_version')
version = parser.parse_args(['--test-version', '1'])

print(version.test_version)
```

or if you want it as a status flag:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="get all versions")
parser.add_argument('--test-version', action='store_true', dest='test_version')
version = parser.parse_args(['--test-version'])

print(version.test_version)
```

Comment: @user1164061 I was missing the second `-` in the argument to add_argument. It works now.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'test'

Comment: @user1164061 Then you didn't copy my code exactly. I promise you this code works.

Comment: None of your solutions work. Have you tested them out?

Comment: Now that you remove the dot from the first line, they work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how those got there, but regardless, it works now.

Comment: You actually don't need `dest='test_version'`. Argparse will convert `--test-version` to `test_version` by default.